# Printing Stack trace element exception

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

The dangerousMethodHandler() prints the stack trace of the error from a StackTraceElement array when an illegal argument exception is caught.  For any other types of exceptions, the dangerousMethodHandler() prints "Exception!"

I currently have sorted out the other exception but can't seem to implement my code using the StackTraceElemen array

```
public void dangerousMethod() {
    Character.toChars(~0);
}

public void dangerousMethodHandler() {
        try {
        this.dangerousMethod();
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){

          StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
            e.getStackTrace();
            System.err.println(trace[0].toString());

       }    catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print("Exception!");
        }

    }
```

When I print out the following I get

```
java.lang.Character.toChars(Character.java:4982)
```

My output should be :

```
java\.lang\.Character\.toChars\(Character\.java:\d+\)[\s\n]+Main\.dangerousMethod\(Main\.java:\d+\)[\s\n]+Main\.dangerousMethodHandler\(Main\.java:\d+\)[\s\n]+Main\.runTests\(Main\.java:\d+\)[\s\n]+Main\.main\(Main\.java:\d+\)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `printStackTrace(System.err)`?

Comment: I get this error if I try Main.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol : method printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream)
location: class Main
printStackTrace(System.err);

Comment: If I go e.printStackTrace(System.err); I get this error which is pretty close java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
\x09at java.lang.Character.toChars(Character.java:4982)
\x09at Main.dangerousMethod(Main.java:18)
\x09at Main.dangerousMethodHandler(Main.java:5)
\x09at Main.runTests(Main.java:26)
\x09at Main.main(Main.java:22)

Comment: I just need to know how to split it all up in the format shown in the "My output should be:"

Answer (score 5):

You're only printing the first StackTraceElement from the array. You'll want to iterate through that and print each.

```
for (StackTraceElement elem : trace) {
    System.err.println(elem);
}
```

Comment: how would you print it out with the backslashes and newlines ?

Comment: I thought your output was regex.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do below:
`Arrays.stream(e.getStackTrace()).skip(0).map(StackTraceElement::toString).reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + "\n" + s2).get()`

In reduce you can define how to construct your string. Maybe it would help you.